# Ruby - Parse timestamp as though it's in a specific timezone

Tags: ruby, timezone, mixpanel

I'm exporting some data from Mixpanel and am trying to read in a timestamp. However, Mixpanel sends timestamps in something other than UTC.

#### Mixpanel Docs

> Timestamps are expressed in seconds since January 1, 1970 **in your project's timezone, not UTC as a true epoch timestamp.** For example, if your project is set to Pacific time, you would need to add 8 hours (or 7 hours if not in daylights savings time) (60 min * 60 secs * 8 hours) to the timestamp in order to convert this timestamp into UTC. This means that converting the raw exported timestamps using many epoch converters will result in representing times with the incorrect offset.

#### Example

`1492100624` is a timestamp from mixpanel and it corresponds to `04/13/2017 @ 4:23pm (Central Time US)`. If I use `Time.at` to parse the timestamp it assumes the timestamp is in UTC.

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.at 1492100624
=> 2017-04-13 11:23:44 -0500
irb(main):002:0> Time.at(1492100624).utc
=> 2017-04-13 16:23:44 UTC .   # correct time in the wrong timezone
```

Manually adding in 7 or 8 hours as per their docs seems prone to errors depending on if the timestamp falls before or after daylight savings. Then again, timezones are confusing, so I could be making this harder than it seems!

How should I go about correctly reading in these timestamps so I can operate on them in UTC?

Note: I'm not using rails. How can I do this in vanilla Ruby?

Comment: is it a rails application or you do it in plain ruby?

Comment: Not rails, plain vanilla ruby script - added to question.

Comment: _.utc in your example gives you the correct time in the wrong timezone.

Comment: yeah, it was my mistake. I submit my solution. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to be working for me:

```
t = Time.at 1492100624 // => 2017-04-13 11:23:44 -0500
t -= t.utc_offset      // => 2017-04-13 16:23:44 -0500
```

Comment: This is the best you can do I think, but it is important to note that it does not solve the problem completely, because some "timezoned" timestamps can resolve to two different epoch timestamps (particularly at DST change). This is the very reason why epoch timestamp is defined as UTC: without that timestamps are useless as unique identifiers of time points. Without any experience with Mixpanel, I would consider this as a bug.